# Questions related to API implementation using NodeJS and Java

Tags: rest

6. What to consider if choosing Java over NodeJS in terms of API?
7. At what condition we should use Java as an API?
8. What Java environments are needed to build an API?
9. Can NodeJS API development can be considered easier than Java API?
10. What NodeJS environments are needed to build an API?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -2):

6. Java performance is faster than node.js, that's the reason why choose java over node.js.
7. When you need performance and secure.
8. Java APIs are highly flexible and adaptable because they can easily accept feature updates and changes to frameworks and operating environments.
9. Node.js environment offers fast and easy code writing due to its simple syntax and interpreted code. Overall, it is easy to grasp, especially for developers skilled in JavaScript. Java, on the other hand, has a slightly steeper learning curve, as it has a very broad ecosystem.
10. Node.js need node.js and express to make API using node.js and offers fast and easy code writing due to its simple syntax and interpreted code.

Comment: This answer contains a few factual errors. It also mischaracterizes both Java and Javascript, except for the places where it's so vague that it can't be understood.